# Regular expression flags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Can someone explain what the 'e' flag does, or link me to somewhere that does? I couldn't find anything via google.

Example:

```
preg_replace("/a(b?)c/e", "search_foo_term('\$1')", $str);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **e (PREG_REPLACE_EVAL)**
>
> If this modifier
>   is set, preg_replace() does normal
>   substitution of backreferences in the
>   replacement string, evaluates it as
>   PHP code, and uses the result for
>   replacing the search string. Single
>   quotes, double quotes, backslashes ()
>   and NULL chars will be escaped by
>   backslashes in substituted
>   backreferences. Only preg_replace()
>   uses this modifier; it is ignored by
>   other PCRE functions.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

So given this example:

```
preg_replace("/a(b?)c/e", "search_foo_term('\$1')", $str);
```

The replacement for the entire match will be what search_foo_term() returns when passed the match for b? .

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Modifiers".

Answer (score 2):

The e flag is deprecated, mostly for security reasons. Use  `preg_replace_callback` instead.